# how to make multiple objects using the same class, but with different names.in python?

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I'm trying to make a discord bot that can create objects with unique names but by using same class for each object. I want it to be able to have each user do a discord command to make it create an object named after their discord id ex. user_0001, user_0002, user_0003. and then be able to access them based on their discord id later on.

```
user_list = []
obj_dict = {}


@client.command()
async def start(ctx):
    author_id = ctx.message.author.id
    user_id = "user_" + str(author_id)
    if user_id not in user_list:
        user_list.append(user_id)
        await ctx.send("player created")
        user_list[-1] = objects.PStats # tried using lists but then it just reasigns it to the object
        obj_dict[user_list[-1]] = objects.PStats
```

Comment: You should probably learn the basics of Python before creating a discord bot. What even is `objects.PStats`?

Comment: @Cloud objects refers to a module i made and pstats refers to the class i'm trying to make objects from.